# How can I define what TFS user to use in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline

I have created jenkins on linux machine and trying to connect it to TFS projects. we created jenkins user in NIS and configured jenkins to use NIS credentials. when I login into the linux machine (master) I see that jenkins pulls (git) TFS projects as root and not as jenkins user. how can I make jenkins run jobs as jenkins and not as root ?
using pipeline.

Comment: what user you defined in source code management?

Comment: I didn't defined it. using pipeline.

Comment: Do you use TFS plugin, what's your jenkins version?

Comment: So what does your pipeline look like? Or your SCM configuration. If you using GIT you would normally add the credentials when you define the SCM for the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins Pipeline support was just added in [TFS plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31803) latest version 5.126.0.

You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/releases) and view [issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/pull/176).

In [Settings enter user and password](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md):

> Team Foundation Server (on-premises)
> For [on-premises] Team Foundation Server, the User name can be specified in two ways:
>
> EXAMPLE-DOMAIN\user
>
> user@domain.example.com